# OpenGL E.S. 2.0: Very inconsistent framerate

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have created a simple Android application like this:

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}
```

**OpenGL Surface:**

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(new MyGL20Renderer());
    }
}
```

**Renderer:**

```
public class MyGL20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private long mCurrentTime;

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        final long newTime = getSystemTime();
        final long dt = newTime - mCurrentTime;
        mCurrentTime = newTime;

        Log.e("test", "dt: "+dt);

        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    private long getSystemTime() {
        return System.nanoTime()/1000L;
    }

}
```

As you can see, for each frame I take the nanoTime and divide it by 1000 to get micro-second times.

Now, when I look at the output produced in `onDrawFrame()`, I get all ways of different values:

[image]
(Original size here: http://s14.directupload.net/images/131026/97pse5wo.png).

The **x-scale** is simply the frames. One value per frame. The **y-scale** is the delta-time, dt calculated in `onDrawFrame()`. This is the time in microseconds it took for the previous frame to draw.

Now I perfectly understand, that the values aren't staying on 16666 due to the following reasons:

- Delta time cannot be determined perfectly. Also, dividing the nanotime by 1000 and casting it to a `long` causes some calculation errors
- The system has to await for `eglSwapBuffers()`
- Once the function `onDrawFrame()` has finished, this does only mean that OpenGL commands have sent to the pipeline. But it does not mean that the commands have been processed.

But still I can't seem to understand why I get so high jittering results, while I'm basically calculating nothing.

What may be the source of the problem?

Test-Environment:

- HTC One
- CyanogenMod 10.2 (Android 4.3)

If anybody else could reproduce this, I would be very glad.

Answer (score -1):

You'll find that the inconsistent frame rate is due to the Log statement.  If you store up the data points, and then log them all at once, you will see that the framerates are much more consistent.  Use something like the following to log the data.  I did it every 1000 frames and got dt's of around 16500-18500.

```
    mDt[mStoredDtCount] = dt;
    mStoredDtCount++;
    if (mStoredDtCount == DT_MAX_COUNT) {
        while (mStoredDtCount > 0) {
            mStoredDtCount--;
            Log.e("test2", "dt: "+mDt[mStoredDtCount]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if this is really it. I have done it using your method and now get this graph (About one minute captured):
http://s14.directupload.net/images/131026/m7bg6dd8.png

Comment: My only other thought is to see if your device is doing garbage collecting between frames.

Comment: I have removed the filter from the log output and set it to "verbose". there is not a single message regarding GC during the whole runtime.

Comment: If you care to zip and upload your source code somewhere, I will try your code on my device.

Comment: Hi levis501, thanks for your answer.
I have uploaded a zip here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8228041/FramerateTest.zip.html
It contains the .apk as well as the sourcecode.

Comment: I'm seeing much more consistent frame rates than you are.  http://pastebin.com/dzY1UK73 for my results.  Except for 4 or 5 outlying data points, dt has a mean of 17.2 ms with a standard deviation of 0.5 ms.  In other words, 95% of the data points lie within 16.2ms and 18.2ms.  The differences between our experiments are 1) I'm using a stock kernel and 2) I have different hardware (Galaxy Nexus).  Anyone else able to test this?

Comment: Yesterday I tried it with a stock rom, with these results: http://s7.directupload.net/images/131028/7i8o2rjq.png
blue curve is cyanogenmod 10.2, red curve is stock rom (Android 4.3).
Stock rom seems to be much better than cyanogenmod, but it seems still jittering. Also there are still large spikes.
Can anybody try it on another HTC One maybe?